# "react-scripts build" is updating my "jsx":"react" to "jsx":"react-jsx" in tsconfig.json file

Tags: create-react-app

When I run

> react-scripts build

I get the following message :

> ```
> The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:
>   - compilerOptions.jsx must be react-jsx (to support the new JSX transform in React 17)
> ```

However I do not have **React 17**. It is not installed, or in my package.json file.

The only thing I did was upgrade to React 17 a few days ago to play around with it, but then I reverted. Everything is back to 16.

Why does react-scripts think it should update my JSX?

Answer (score 0):

I just realised what the problem was.

I had a **package.json** file one level up from my actual project. It was there by accident. Inside the "parent" package.json I had React 17 defined.

```
package.json
|
|----- package.json
```

It seems like npm or CRA is behaving like Maven and trying to recursivley process build scripts up the folder tree.